# IEnumerable OrderByDescending vs Reverse()

Tags: entity-framework, sorting, ienumerable, reverse

I have an IEnumerable of database objects retrieved through:

```
var customers = _dbcontext.Customer.Where(x => x.ClientId > 0 && x.isDeleted == null);
customers = sortCustomers(customers, sortOrder, sortDirection);
```

To sort that IEnumerable customers, i have a method called `SortCustomers()` (implemented below) which maps `sortOrder` argument to the property to use for sorting. It also uses `sortDirection` to determine if to use descending or ascending direction.

I initially used `orderBy()` which will be ascending, and then use `Reverse()` on the final result if descending direction was specified.

The other option which produces longer and duplicate code is to use OrderByDescending() at each step (see code below).

Does using IEnumerable<>.Reverse() do the same as OrderByDescending() in this case (without cancelling out lazy loading)?

- Option 1:

  ```
  private IEnumerable<Customer> sortCustomers(IEnumerable<Customer> unsortedCustomers, string sortOrder, string sortDirection)
  {
      if (sortOrder == MODEL.VMSortDescriptors.CustomerVMSortDescriptor.CompanyName.ToString())
      {
          unsortedCustomers = unsortedCustomers.OrderBy(c => c.CompanyName);
      }
      else if (sortOrder == MODEL.VMSortDescriptors.CustomerVMSortDescriptor.ContactPerson.ToString())
      {
          unsortedCustomers = unsortedCustomers.OrderBy(c => c.ContactPerson);
      }
      else if (sortOrder == MODEL.VMSortDescriptors.CustomerVMSortDescriptor.EmailId.ToString())
      {
          unsortedCustomers = unsortedCustomers.OrderBy(c => c.EmailId);
      }
      //many more sort properties

      //Asc or Desc
      if (sortDirection == VMSortDescriptors.SortDirection.Descending.ToString())
          unsortedCustomers = unsortedCustomers.Reverse();

      return unsortedCustomers;
  }
  ```
- Option 2:

  ```
  private IEnumerable<Customer> sortCustomers(IEnumerable<Customer> unsortedCustomers, string sortOrder, string sortDirection)
  {
      bool isAscendingOrder = (sortDirection == VMSortDescriptors.SortDirection.Ascending.ToString());

      if (sortOrder == MODEL.VMSortDescriptors.CustomerVMSortDescriptor.CompanyName.ToString())
      {
          if (isAscendingOrder)
              unsortedCustomers = unsortedCustomers.OrderBy(c => c.CompanyName);
          else
              unsortedCustomers = unsortedCustomers.OrderByDescending(c => c.CompanyName);
      }
      else if (sortOrder == MODEL.VMSortDescriptors.CustomerVMSortDescriptor.ContactPerson.ToString())
      {
          if (isAscendingOrder)
              unsortedCustomers = unsortedCustomers.OrderBy(c => c.ContactPerson);
          else
              unsortedCustomers = unsortedCustomers.OrderByDescending(c => c.ContactPerson);
      }
      else if (sortOrder == MODEL.VMSortDescriptors.CustomerVMSortDescriptor.EmailId.ToString())
      {
          if (isAscendingOrder)
              unsortedCustomers = unsortedCustomers.OrderBy(c => c.EmailId);
          else
              unsortedCustomers = unsortedCustomers.OrderByDescending(c => c.EmailId);
      }
      //many more sort properties

      return unsortedCustomers;
  }
  ```

---

**UPDATE**

Regarding mapping the sortOrder argument to the property, yes I could use reflection or something to get the property value on the items in the IEnumerable. I did that initially, with a generic sorting function. But things got complicated with anonymous tupled results. So I decided to go simple and straight forward.

Comment: `IEnumerable.Reverse` still uses deferred execution so there's probably not a lot of difference in your 2 methods. `IQueryable.Reverse` may work differently though. You should really benchmark them yourself. Also, check the SQL that is generated.

Comment: Having said that, I have a feeling that EF Core might not like `Reverse`.

Comment: @DavidG you are right. I have to do `AsEnumerable().Reverse()`

Comment: The problem with that method is it's being done locally and will cause entity framework to materialise the query.

Comment: It's a bit confusing to see the method `sortCustomers()` return `unsortedCustomers` variable..

Comment: @ErikPhilips yes you are right. But besides that bit, do you see any issues with using `Reverse()` ?

Comment: As mentioned before, `reverse()` will do it client side.  Probably more peformant to let the server do it ([.OrderByDescending()]).

Comment: @ErikPhilips makes sense. Is there a way I can confirm this?

Comment: @pnizzle it depends on who's running the client side code and how beefy your server is.  So not really.